# Java Config for Spring Gemfire xml

Tags: spring-data, spring-java-config, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I've defined my Gemfire's "client-cache.xml" as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <gfe:pool id="client" subscription-enabled="true">
    <gfe:locator host="localhost" port="41114"/>
    </gfe:pool>

    <gfe:client-cache pool-name="client"/>

    <gfe:client-region id="dataRegion" name="dataRegion" pool-name="client" shortcut="PROXY"/>

</beans>
```

I want to create a corresponding Java Configuration for the same.

I've tried below configuration:

```
@Resource
private Cache gemfireCache;

@Resource
private Pool client;

@Bean
public PoolFactoryBean client() {
    PoolFactoryBean client = new PoolFactoryBean();
    client.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
    client.addLocators(new ConnectionEndpoint("localhost", 41114));
    return client;
}

@Bean
public ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, AbstractContent> dataRegion() {
    ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, AbstractContent> dataRegionFactory = new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();
    dataRegionFactory.setPoolName("client");
    dataRegionFactory.setName("dataRegion");
    dataRegionFactory.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);
    return dataRegionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {
    ClientCacheFactoryBean clientCacheFactory = new ClientCacheFactoryBean();
    clientCacheFactory.setPoolName("client");
    clientCacheFactory.setPdxSerializer(mappingPdxSerializer());
    return clientCacheFactory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager gemfireTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    return new GemfireTransactionManager(gemfireCache);
}
```

However, I keep running into exception saying :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCache] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:369)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.PoolFactoryBean.eagerlyInitializeClientCacheIfNotPresent(PoolFactoryBean.java:218)
at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.PoolFactoryBean.getObject(PoolFactoryBean.java:171)
at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.PoolFactoryBean.getObject(PoolFactoryBean.java:65)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1590)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

Is it not possible to transform the above XML into Java based configuration?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

===============Edited below per John's comments==============

@John,

I tried the example mentioned @ [sample test case for gemfire client](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/src/test/java/io/pivotal/gemfire/cache/client/SpringGemFireClientCacheTest.java) and the sample as it is, worked fine.
I'm using locator and the example worked fine with the locators configuration as
`gemfirePool.setLocators(Collections.singletonList(new InetSocketAddress(host, port)))`.
However, I'm using spring-data-gemfire version 1.8.2.RELEASE as per recommendations of Pivotal support.
So, I

- upgraded the spring-data-gemfire version to 1.8.2.RELEASE @ [pom.xml](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/pom.xml),
- fixed the compilation errors
  (commented `gemfireCache.setLazyInitialize(true)`),
- and changed `gemfirePool.setLocators(Collections.singletonList(new InetSocketAddress(locatorHost, locatorPort)))` to `gemfirePool.addLocators(Collections.singletonList(new ConnectionEndpoint(locatorHost, locatorPort)))`,

the test case went for a toss.

The test case started giving me below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfireCache' defined in io.pivotal.gemfire.cache.client.SpringGemFireClientCacheTest$SpringGemFireClientConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.Pool]: : Error creating bean with name 'gemfirePool': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCache] is defined; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfirePool': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCache] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfirePool': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCache] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.ClientCache] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.PoolFactoryBean.eagerlyInitializeClientCacheIfNotPresent(PoolFactoryBean.java:218)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.PoolFactoryBean.getObject(PoolFactoryBean.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.client.PoolFactoryBean.getObject(PoolFactoryBean.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 52 more
```

So, it looks like, it's an issue with the spring-data-gemfire 1.8.2.RELEASE.
I'm not really sure if I should simply revert back to 1.6.2.RELEASE and, what would I lose on reverting back to a previous revision.

I created another sample spring boot application:

- pom.xml

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0
      com.cdk.test
      TestGemfireLocators
      0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

  ```
  <parent>
      <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ```
- Application.java

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Bean(name = "region")
  public ClientRegionFactoryBean region(ClientCache gemfireCache, Pool gemfirePool) {
      ClientRegionFactoryBean versionedRegion = new ClientRegionFactoryBean();
      versionedRegion.setName("region");
      versionedRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
      versionedRegion.setPool(gemfirePool);
      versionedRegion.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);
      return versionedRegion;
  }

  @Bean
  public ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache(@Qualifier("gemfireProperties") Properties gemfireProperties,
          Pool gemfirePool) {
      ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new ClientCacheFactoryBean();
      gemfireCache.setPool(gemfirePool);
      gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties);
      return gemfireCache;
  }

  @Bean(name = GemfireConstants.DEFAULT_GEMFIRE_POOL_NAME)
  public PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool(@Value("${locator.host}") String host, @Value("${locator.port}") int port) {
      PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool = new PoolFactoryBean();
      gemfirePool.setName(GemfireConstants.DEFAULT_GEMFIRE_POOL_NAME);
      gemfirePool.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
      gemfirePool.addLocators(new ConnectionEndpoint(host, port));
      return gemfirePool;
  }

  @Bean
  public Properties gemfireProperties(@Value("${gemfire.log.level:config}") String logLevel) {
      Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
      gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", logLevel);
      return gemfireProperties;
  }
  ```

  }

The above code too, doesn't work and returns same exception. I tried above code with the default version of "spring-data-gemfire" contained with-in `io.spring.platform` (1.7.4.RELEASE) and still the same result.

-------------POST John's comments and reference program-------------------

Thanks a lot John. The sample provided by you helped me, however, I had to make a few changes to the code. Below is how my final project looks like (if you notice, I'm injecting `GemfireCache` instead of `ClientCache`):

- pom.xml

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0
      com.cdk.test
      TestGemfireLocators
      0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

  ```
  <parent>
      <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-gemfire</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ```
- Application.java

  @SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Resource(name = "myRegion")
  private Region<String, Object> myRegion;

  int intValue(Long value) {
      return value.intValue();
  }

  String logLevel() {
      return System.getProperty("gemfire.log-level", "config");
  }

  Properties gemfireProperties() {
      Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
      gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", logLevel());
      return gemfireProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {
      ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new ClientCacheFactoryBean();

      gemfireCache.setClose(true);
      gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties());

      return gemfireCache;
  }

  @Bean(name = GemfireConstants.DEFAULT_GEMFIRE_POOL_NAME)
  PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool(@Value("${locator.host}") String host, @Value("${locator.port}") int port) {

      PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool = new PoolFactoryBean();

      gemfirePool.setKeepAlive(false);
      gemfirePool.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
      gemfirePool.setThreadLocalConnections(false);

      gemfirePool.addLocators(new ConnectionEndpoint(host, port));

      return gemfirePool;
  }

  @Bean(name = "myRegion")
  ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Object> myRegion(@Value("${region.name}") String regionName, GemFireCache gemfireCache,
          Pool gemfirePool) {
      ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, Object> myRegion = new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();

      myRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
      myRegion.setName(regionName);
      myRegion.setPool(gemfirePool);
      myRegion.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);

      return myRegion;
  }

  @Bean
  PlatformTransactionManager gemfireTransactionManager(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {
      return new GemfireTransactionManager((Cache) gemfireCache);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: > "it's an issue with the spring-data-gemfire 1.8.2.RELEASE"... Not likely!  FYI, I just updated the pivotal-gemfire-clientsever-examples project to use Spring Data GemFire 1.8.2.RELEASE along with Spring Boot 1.4.0.RC1 and all works as expected.  Specifically, I ran the spring-gemfire-clientserver example (that showcases the Java-based configuration) and it worked with GemFire 8.2.0, SDG 1.8.2.RELEASE and Spring Boot 1.4.0.RC1.  Next, I will play with your configuration above and see what is going on.  Stay tuned...

Comment: Alright, following up... I took your example Spring (client) configuration almost exactly as is (with only minor, insignificant modifications) and coded up an example test with both a Spring Boot GemFire Server application and GemFire cache client application test class.  You can see the complete code here (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/tree/master/src/test/java/org/stackoverflow/questions/xml_to_javaconfig).  You can even connect to the Spring Boot-based GemFire Server from Gfsh once running and monitor things there.  This test worked as expected!

Comment: Thanks John !!! Will give it a shot and hopefully, it'll work. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks John. I was able to get my project up. I've posted my configurations.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you got it working.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` pertains to the injected `Cache` reference in your application Java configuration class...

```
@Resource
private Cache gemfireCache
```

> NOTE: you might prefer to use `@Inject` or *Spring's* `@Autowired` annotation instead, since this is technically more accurate.

The problem here is there is no *Spring* bean defined of type "`Cache`" in your *Spring* Java configuration.

If you [look](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.8.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/client/ClientCacheFactoryBean.java#L368-L372) more closely at the `ClientCacheFactoryBean`, `getObjectType()` method, which *Spring* uses to inspect bean (definitions) during autowiring of application components "by type", you see that it returns `ClientCache.class`.  Technically, `ClientCacheFactoryBean.getObjectType()` also returns the actual cache object's type, but I do not recall when *Spring* inspects the available bean definitions to resolve type dependencies.  Plus, I think the *Spring* container also maintains a type-to-bean mapping (a.k.a. cache) during parsing.  The only reason the later is relevant is because GemFire only has 1 implementation of `Cache` and `ClientCache`, and that implementation, namely [GemFireCacheImpl](https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/blob/rel/v1.0.0-incubating.M2/geode-core/src/main/java/com/gemstone/gemfire/internal/cache/GemFireCacheImpl.java#L250) implements both interfaces.  So, it seemingly should be resolvable, but...

Anyway, all of this is to explain the exception with a bit more clarity.

Unfortunately, you cannot use...

```
return new GemfireTransactionManager(gemfireCache());
```

Since the `gemfireCache()` bean definition "method" returns an instance of the `ClientCacheFactoryBean` and the `GemfireTransactionManager` constructor expects an instance of `Cache`.

However, you can define arguments of type `Cache`, `ClientCache` and `GemFireCache` as needed by the SDG `FactoryBeans`.  For instance, your `gemfireTransactionManager` bean can be defined as...

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager gemfireTransactionManager(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {
  return new GemfireTransactionManager((Cache) gemfireCache));
}
```

> NOTE: `ClientCache` extends `GemFireCache`.

Likewise, your *Region* bean definition, "`dataRegion`" also expects and can take an instance of the cache like so...

```
@Bean
public ClientRegionFactoryBean<String, AbstractContent> dataRegion(ClientCache gemfireCache, Pool gemfirePool) {
  ...
  dataRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
  dataRegion.setPool(gemfirePool);
  ...
}
```

Also notice, I can pass a reference to the GemFire Pool that the *Region* should use for data access operations to the cluster servers.

Spring treats Java configuration `@Bean` definition method parameters as "type dependencies", so you can just defined the expected, resulting bean type required by the bean component in question (e.g. "gemfireTransactionManager" which expects a "Cache" bean dependency).

In general, there is no problem switching from XML to Java configuration.  In fact, I encourage it and have even been using Java config more and more in my examples (for [instance](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples)).  In time I plan to convert most of the [spring-gemfire-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples) over to using *Spring Boot* and Java configuration.

Speaking of the [spring-gemfire-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples), there is also an [example with Java config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-gemfire-examples/tree/master/basic/java-config).  But, I think this example demonstrates a peer cache.  So, you may find the examples in [3](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples) more helpful since I compare and contrast both GemFire native configuration and Spring configuration using both XML and Java.

For instance, my `ClientCache` Java configuration example has both a GemFire Cache [server Java config](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/src/main/java/io/pivotal/gemfire/main/SpringGemFireServerApplication.java) and [client Java config](https://github.com/jxblum/pivotal-gemfire-clientserver-examples/blob/master/spring-gemfire-clientserver/src/test/java/io/pivotal/gemfire/cache/client/SpringGemFireClientCacheTest.java#L92-L157).

Anyway, hope this helps and if you more questions, feel free to reach out.

Cheers,
John

Update - 2016-07-19

Example (& test) for this problem using your GemFire cache client, Spring Java configuration provided [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/tree/master/src/test/java/org/stackoverflow/questions/xml_to_javaconfig).

Comment: Thanks John! I'll try it out and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bean method instead of @Resource, e.g.

```
return new GemfireTransactionManager(gemfireCache());
```

Answer (score 0):

Running spring boot tests with Geode I had startup error like this (paths redacted):

`Invalid bean definition with name 'gemfireCache' defined in class path resource...  CacheServerConfiguration...  There is already...  ClientCacheConfiguration... defined in class path resource... bound`

It was fixed by adding
`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to my `application.properties` file